# How to test bottomSheet-controller containing locals in jasmine?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am using the angular-material bottomSheet using the locals to pass an object (see here: https://material.angularjs.org/#/api/material.components.bottomSheet/service/$mdBottomSheet ).
Now I am confused about how you would correctly test them in jasmine/karma.
Below is the usual way of injecting; the way I tried to inject my local (myLocal).

```
beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope, _myLocal_) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    myLocal = _myLocal_;
    UserActionsCtrl = $controller('UserActionsCtrl', {
        $scope: scope
    });
}));
```

That gives me the following error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: myLocalProvider <- myLocal
```

Of course there is nothing to be found, since I didn't call the bottomSheet with the filled locals. But all attempts to mock them failed. If anyone knows, how the locals can be mocked, I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close sir!

I take it your controller declaration looks something like this:

```
.controller('UserActionsCtrl', function ($scope, $mdBottomSheet, myLocal)
```

I know that the Angular Material provides it through their 'locals' argument in the options parameter as it [says here](https://material.angularjs.org/#/api/material.components.bottomSheet/service/$mdBottomSheet), but you just assume that it's the same as any other controller sharing data with another controller where you pull it in as a provider to the receiving controller, so your tests just reflect it!

Try this instead, you must provide the value into the controller instance as so:

```
beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    var myLocal = {};
    UserActionsCtrl = $controller('UserActionsCtrl', {
        $scope: scope,
        myLocal: myLocal
    });
}));
```